# Sub Query Issues

Tags: oracle

Recently our DB server changed and after that sub query started giving performance issue.

Example :

```
select * from table1 a where col1  = 
       (select max(col1) from table1 b where a.p1=b.p1)
```

This pattern is available at many places so NOT looking to change query but any database level changes should be fine. Looking for which DB parameters can cause performance Issue.

Comment: What did you change about the DB server and how did you do it? This query pattern used to be incredibly slow but would have seen improvements in later versions of Oracle where it will rewrite it for you. Did you downgrade? Did you change the optimizer parameters in the new server so that they correspond to much older versions?

Comment: @AndrewSayer - Earlier was 10g and now moved to 19c due to oracle support, not aware about optimizer parameters, which one I need to worry about for mentioned sql ? and how I can check those in DB, if any link/article which can guide that will be really helpful.

Comment: @AndrewSayer : I found this v$sys_optimizer_env view, I compared values between old and new server, most of them are same, noticable difference  for pga_aggregate_target in old server much higher than new. can it cause an issue ?

Answer (score 0):

The optimizer should be able to rewrite your query in the following, more efficient form (but it probably can't do it if your query is much more complicated than that, involving many joins, etc. - assuming your example is much simplified just to illustrate the problem):

```
select * from table1 where (p1, col1) in 
  (select p1, max(col1) from table1 group by p1);
```

If the optimizer doesn't (or can't, for some reason) rewrite the query this way, then it will obviously be slow, since it must read the table repeatedly - once for each row in the table.

Another common way to get the same result (but experimentation shows that it is often slower, even though it only reads the base table once, vs. twice with the solution above) uses analytic functions:

```
select * -- or just the columns from table1, without rnk
from   (
         select t.*, 
                dense_rank() over (partition by p1
                                  order by col1 desc nulls last) as rnk
         from   table1 t
       )
where  rnk = 1
;
```

Comment: yes we have many joins etc but this pattern is available at many places hence not looking for query change at this stage. Looking for DB parameter change so that optimizer start using earlier plan. This was executing fine for many years and after recent DB server change we started facing this problem

Comment: @12345 - Why do you think the slower execution is due to DB parameter change (and not, for example, to table stats which existed on the old server, but were not gathered when you changed the server)?

Comment: table stats are fine, initially we thought about it but then we gathered STATS on all the tables in schema, still no luck :(